Infinite horizontal scroll animation
I am trying to make an infinite scrolling animation without "blinking" and empty spaces. The problem is when I'm using max-width of 1300px and my text inside list element is short, I still get this "blinking" effect and a lot of empty space between last and first element. I suppose I need to do some kinda calculations in my calc function, but I can't wrap my head around it. Do you have any ideas?


const scrollers = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller");

if (!window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)").matches) {
  addAnimation();
}

function addAnimation() {
  scrollers.forEach((scroller) => {
    scroller.setAttribute("data-animated", true);

    const scrollerInner = scroller.querySelector(".scroller__inner");
    const scrollerContent = Array.from(scrollerInner.children);

    scrollerContent.forEach((item) => {
      const duplicatedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
      duplicatedItem.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true);
      scrollerInner.appendChild(duplicatedItem);
    });
  });
}
.scroller {
  max-width: 1300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.scroller__inner {
  padding-block: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.scroller[data-animated="true"] {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroller[data-animated="true"] .scroller__inner {
  width: max-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  animation: scroll var(--_animation-duration, 40s)
    var(--_animation-direction, forwards) linear infinite;
}

.scroller[data-direction="right"] {
  --_animation-direction: reverse;
}

.scroller[data-direction="left"] {
  --_animation-direction: forwards;
}

.scroller[data-speed="fast"] {
  --_animation-duration: 20s;
}

.scroller[data-speed="slow"] {
  --_animation-duration: 60s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  to {
    transform: translate(calc(-50% - 0.5rem));
  }
}

/* general styles */
body {
  display: grid;
  min-block-size: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.tag-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding-inline: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tag-list li {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
<div class="scroller" data-speed="fast">
  <ul class="tag-list scroller__inner">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>




I've inserted your current code you've posted here into a basic HTML doc, and it doesn't seem to do any scrolling or animation of any kind at all. If you post code that shows the actual issue (blinking, etc.) when it's run, then it will be much easier to see what you're trying to do, and help! As it is, I just see a bunch of wrapped items. If you post a working example as a Stack Snippet, even better, and you'll probably get a quick answer!

Thanks for tip @Snor! I've added a code snippet. It should be working better now.
